# Changing value of a field of an object inside an ArrayList using stream, making code more efficient

Tags: java, object, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I have inside an `ArrayList` with a finite number of objects. I want to look inside the list for a specific value in the field and then change it.

I have the following implementation.

```java
String searchName = searchedName; //from outside we provide this
Person person = personList.stream()
        .filter(personList -> searchName.equals(personList.getName()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
if (person != null){
    person.setName(replacement);
}
```

This code works, but streams aren't my specialty, my question is: can I have the same behavior with the difference that I don't need to make the extra if? I feel like the "if" is something extra and I would like to make my code more efficient.

A side question is there a way to use the stream in case we have multiple entries with the same name, so instead of ".findFirst()  .orElse(null)" what can I use to store it inside the person object or possible new array of objects.

Comment: I would suggest using a classical for/while loop for that task, if your list is huge. or you do this operation many times.

Comment: Of course the most performant way would be to have a `Map<String, Person>`, but it probably doesn't make a difference, unless your list is large and you're doing lots of lookups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reduce the code by using `Optional#isPresent`:

```
personList.stream()
          .filter(personList -> searchName.equals(personList.getName()))
          .findFirst()
          .ifPresent(person -> person.setName(replacement));
```

But if I was aiming for performance, streams wouldn't be my first choice.

If you want to process all objects, that fulfill the predicate:

```
personList.stream()
          .filter(personList -> searchName.equals(personList.getName()))
          .forEach(person -> person.setName(replacement));
```

Comment: you have a nice sollution,but I get an error.
when I add person..setName I get Syntax error on token ".", ElidedSemicolonAndRightBrace expected

but with only one "." I get Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Person.  It seems a little strange

Comment: Typo: `person..setName` should only have 1 dot. --- Copy/paste: Both code blocks have that typo.

Comment: with only 1 dot there is also an error Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Person and says it can't re declare another local variable in an enclosing scope , don't understand why

Comment: @BlajBogdan notice that this answer’s solution does not have the `Person person = …` assignment. Use the code as written in this answer, except for the two dots.

Comment: Corrected the typo, thank you very much for this notice!